# Writing a glob-match testing function

Tags: wildcards

In a higher-level programming language I am working on writing a `wildcardMatch(input, pattern)` function that I want to work exactly like the glob matching in Unix.

To do this I have been using property-based testing to generate random input and test it against my implementation and the Unix implementation and then comparing that their return values are the same.

My problem is that I don't trust my simple Unix helper script:

```
#!/bin/bash

## Created for development/testing
##
## Example Usage:
##  ./wildcard_test.sh "foobar" "fooba*"

string=$1
pattern=$2

if [[ $string == $pattern ]]; then
  echo 0
  exit 0
else
  echo 1
  exit 1
fi
```

Everything was working fine until I learned that the expansion would happen before the script actually runs:

```
./wildcart_test.sh "foo" "???"
```

In that example, the question marks will be expanded to actually match other files in that directory causing the `==` comparison to fail.  In this case it was expanding to `lib`, for example.

---

Is there a better way to test glob matching?

Comment: If you ran your script with `bash` and in exactly the way you show, then the `???` pattern would _not_ be expanded to any existing filenames in the current directory. Can you show some sort of transcript of this actually happening?

Comment: Oh, I think I have confused myself a little bit - I was simply adding `echo $pattern` before the comparison and there it was outputting `lib`, but it seems that the comparison actually did succeed.

Comment: Yes, the unquoted `$pattern` would be causing globbing to occur. Do look at [Stéphane Chazelas' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/556371/116858) for a more portable test though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,

```
./wildcart_test.sh "foo" "???"
```

is fine as that `???` is quoted, so not expanded by your shell. Note however that the `\`, `$` and `` ` `` characters are still special within double quotes. You may want to use single quotes, inside which no character is special (in Bourne-like shells).

One thing you could do here though is remove the `bash` dependency and do it with standard `sh` syntax:

```
#! /bin/sh -
subject=${1?No subject} pattern=${2?No pattern}
case $subject in
  ($pattern) echo 1; true;;
  (*)        echo 0; false;;
esac
```

Note that while a `0` *exit status* means true, it's more customary to use a 0 *number* for false and non-zero for true.

Note however that with `sh`, to be portable, `[^x]` needs to be written `[!x]` as `[^x]` is still not standard.

And whether `\` in `$pattern` is treated specially by the pattern matching code also depends on the implementation and version. `that-script '\foo' '\*'` may return false on some and true on others. Same for`that-script '*' '\*'`.

To match on a literal backslash, use `that-script '\foo' '[\\]*'`. To match on a wildcard character (`?`, `*`, `[`), use `that-script '*?[' '[*][?][[]'`. Also beware of a bug/misfeature in the Bourne shell and its descendants (ksh88, ksh93): both `that-script a '[a]'` and `that-script '[a]' '[a]'` would return *true* on systems where `/bin/sh` is based on AT&T ksh.

Comment: I think I am getting myself confused about expansion because I am trying to solve debug why the following case returns "no match":

`./wildcart_test.sh "\\" "\\"`

I started adding `echo` statements and in those statements the expansion was happening.  I am still unsure why the double backslashes do not match.

Comment: @TylerAndFriends try `'\' '\\'` or `"\\" "\\\\"`

Comment: So the input is interpreted literally while the pattern needs to be escaped?

Comment: @TylerAndFriends, I'm not sure what you mean, but see if the later edits help